# CSS блок по центру экрана

Tags: html, css

Я хочу разместить блок точно по центру экрана (по горизонтали). Для этого я написал нужные стили для `.main`

Блок сдвигается, но уходит вправо больше, чем нужно. Видимо, начало блока позиционируется по центру, но потом содержимое блока смещается правее. Получается не то, что нужно.

Как сделать, чтобы центр экрана был посередине таблицы?

```css
.main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <table class="data" id="celebs">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
        <th>Approx. Location</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some</td>
        <td>other</td>
        <td>thing</td>
        <td>lol</td>
        <td>used</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: А если просто весь блок взять в тег center?

Comment: Таблица не влезает в родительский блок и из-за этого не может правильно центроваться. Надо увеличить его ширину и всё будет хорошо

Comment: или поставить margin-left:40%, а правый убрать полностью

Comment: тоесть сделать прокрутку по x?

Comment: @entithat чтобы центр экрана был посередине таблицы

Comment: енивей нужно поставить либо больше width либо поставить overflow-x:scroll

Comment: @entithat возможно)

Comment: @Art_K, тег `center` устарел лет 10 назад. К тому же всё равно не сработает.

Comment: 10% ширина main ???  а как должна еще вести себя таблица, размер которой на порядок больше?

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность обернуть, то можно использовать какой-то такой "хак":

```css
.main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
}

.main__inner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

.data {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__inner">
    <table class="data" id="celebs">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Occupation</th>
          <th>Approx. Location</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Some</td>
          <td>other</td>
          <td>thing</td>
          <td>lol</td>
          <td>used</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ну или что-то такое:

```css
.main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
}

.data {
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <table class="data" id="celebs">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
        <th>Approx. Location</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some</td>
        <td>other</td>
        <td>thing</td>
        <td>lol</td>
        <td>used</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задайте `margin:auto` для таблицы и уберите ширину для блока-родителя

```css
.data {
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <table class="data" id="celebs">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
        <th>Approx. Location</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some</td>
        <td>other</td>
        <td>thing</td>
        <td>lol</td>
        <td>used</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Flex

Доброго дня. 
Могу предложить использовать **display: flex;**, 
Так как блочные элементы изначально занимают 100% родительского блока, а выше

только body, то данный код выровняет все внутри .main по центру.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <table class="data" id="celebs">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
        <th>Approx. Location</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some</td>
        <td>other</td>
        <td>thing</td>
        <td>lol</td>
        <td>used</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```